# keras.net issue in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to use keras.net in visual studio c# to load my pretrained models in keras. I use the following:

```
var loaded_model = Sequential.ModelFromJson(File.ReadAllText("model1.json"));
loaded_model.LoadWeight("model.h5");
```

when I run my code I get unable to load dll python37 and its dependencies. I tried to put the dll files in the solution directory of the project, but it did not solve the problem.
Does anyone know how I can solve this issue or if there is a better way for loading the trained models.
Thanks in advance for your help.